# Update value of key of a yaml file in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I have a yml file with some key value.

```
age: 24
Name: XYZ
```

I want code to update the value of "Name" key from XYZ to ABC?
How can i do it?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
    require 'yaml'
    data = YAML.load_file "path/to/yml_file.yml"
    data["Name"] = ABC
    File.open("path/to/yml_file.yml", 'w') { |f| YAML.dump(data, f) }
```

It will write into yml file. If specified key ("Name") is not present in file, it will write new key value othrwise the existing one will be replaced.

Comment: Can we write a new value to this data object inside yml file?

Comment: easier to do: `File.write('/path/to/file', 'Some glorious content')`

Comment: I believe this also requires `require 'yaml'`

Comment: I had to open the file in binary mode like this: `File.open("path/to/yml_file.yml", 'wb') { |f| YAML.dump(data, f) }`. Otherwise I got some errors like `/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/emitter.rb:27:in 'write': "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)`

Comment: This method doesn't work if the yaml file contains references (which is a large part of why yaml files are used instead of json). I would post an example here but the markdown is limited.

Comment: This technique deletes comments from the YAML file. (Tested in ruby 3.0.2)