# Reading and updating YAML file by ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have written a yml file like this:

```
last_update: '2014-01-28 11:00:00'
```

I am reading this file as

```
config = YAML.load('config/data.yml')
```

Later I am accessing the last_update_time as config['last_update'] but it is not working. Also I want to update last_update_time by my ruby code like it should update like:

```
 last_update: '2014-01-29 23:59:59'
```

I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Try accessing it using the symbol. `config[:last_update]`

Comment: `YAML.load` tries to parse the string given. Use `YAML.load_file` instead.

Comment: How to update that Yaml file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948951/update-value-of-key-of-a-yaml-file-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Switch .load to .load_file and you should be good to go.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'yaml'
config = YAML.load_file('data.yml')
puts config['last_update']
```

After running this is what I get

```
orcus:~ user$ ruby test.rb
# ⇒ some_data
```

To write the file you will need to open the YAML file and write to the handle. Something like this should work.

```
require 'yaml'
config = YAML.load_file('data.yml')
puts config['last_update'] #in my file this is set to "some data"
config['last_update'] = "other data"
File.open('data.yml','w') do |h| 
   h.write config.to_yaml
end
```

Output was

```
orcus:~ user$ ruby test.rb
some data
orcus:~ user$ cat data.yml
---
last_update: other data
```