# Get variable from yaml in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby, slider, yaml

I have a yaml file with key value pairs in them. I want to use this file to configure a form (titles & DOM slider values).

How do get the key so I can set it equal to ie. `@project_title` and the value so I can set the slider value (jQuery?)?

Comment: Are you asking "How do I write a YAML file, in ruby"? (https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML/Store.html) Your question is very unclear.

Comment: @TomLord No. How do I get Key/Values from yaml to use as variables in rails.

Comment: Your choice of words was very confusing: "How do **get** the key so I can **set it** equal to ... so I can **set the** ..." -- I see now that all you were asking is "How do I read a YAML file". You're not "setting values in the file", you're just assigning variables in javascript. If you'd googled for this, it's [easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21422745/1954610) to find plenty of existing answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading and updating YAML file by ruby code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422494/reading-and-updating-yaml-file-by-ruby-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JustusP to load any YAML file you can simply use built-in YAML `load_file` method

> @yaml_object = YAML.load_file("path_to_file")

This will load the content of YAML file as `HASH` object.

Comment: Thanks! How do I access specific keys/values from the object?

Comment: you can simply use like `@yaml_object['key']` for accessing any object