# Best way to store static metadata in a ruby file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am not sure if the title best describes what I am trying to accomplish here. But basically what I am trying to do is:
Given two files:

```
//example1.txt
some text 

//example1.rb
text = IO.read(example.txt)
var1 = true
var2 = false
```

I will be creating some similar files such as `example2.rb`, `example3.rb`. Then in another ruby file, I would like to read the variables in those config files using syntax such as `example1.text` or `example2.text`.

In Javascript, we can do something like this:

```
//example1.txt
some text 

//example1.js
module.exports = {
    text: load(example1.txt),
    var1: true,
    var2: false
};
```

Then in another file, we can just do

```
var example1 = require("example1.js");
```

And then access the variables using `example1.text`.

Can we do something similar in ruby?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422494/reading-and-updating-yaml-file-by-ruby-code) help ?

Comment: I need to write some ruby code in the config files such as `IO.read()`. I won't be able to do that if I use ymal files.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a config file then, but more like a script

Comment: Actually you are right. I updated my problem description.

Comment: Ruby doesn't have Javascript-style export/imports. You can load up objects from serialized formats like JSON and YAML, but when you require a .rb file, you have to use some sort of global variable such as a constant. E.g. you would define a constant `EXAMPLE_1` within the example_1.rb file then reference that after you've required the file

Comment: are you trying to read `variables` from `.txt` file to `.rb` file? or from one ruby file to another.?