# How to update a value under nested mapped yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a yml like below.

```
ss_usecase_1:
  -    
       key1: "val1" 
       key2: "val2" 
       key3: "45x" 
       key4: 11.26.44.23
       key5: "admin" 
       key6: "CUP" 
       key7: 960

ss_usecase_2:
  -    
       key1: "val3" 
       key2: "val4" 
       key3: "aby45" 
       key4: 11.25.4.26
       key5: "admin" 
       key6: "CUP" 
       key7: 962
```

I would like to update the key6 which is under ss_usecase_2. The below is the way I am trying to update the yml, but it crapping my yml totally. In this process both the master keys's "ss_usecase_1" and "ss_usecase_2" are gone

```
dump_data=YAML::load(File.open("path to yml"))
data=dump_data['ss_usecase_1'][0]

data['key6']="cup1"
File.open("data/synched_services/usecase_1.yml", 'w') { |f| YAML.dump(data, f) }
```

Is there any efficient way to do that without disturbing any of my yml data?

Comment: You did [same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948951/update-value-of-key-of-a-yaml-file-in-ruby-on-rails), no idea why your one didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `dump_data` getting manipulated use [clone](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-clone):

```
data = dump_data['ss_usecase_1'][0].clone
```

> *(clone)* Produces a shallow copy of obj—the instance variables of obj are
>   copied, but not the objects they reference. clone copies the frozen
>   and tainted state of obj.

Example to explain:

```
dump_data['ss_usecase_1'][0]
# => {"key1"=>"val1", "key2"=>"val2", "key3"=>"45x", "key4"=>"11.26.44.23", "key5"=>"admin", "key6"=>"cup1", "key7"=>960}

data = dump_data['ss_usecase_1'][0]
data["key1"] = "abc"
dump_data['ss_usecase_1'][0]
# => {"key1"=>"abc", "key2"=>"val2", "key3"=>"45x", "key4"=>"11.26.44.23", "key5"=>"admin", "key6"=>"cup1", "key7"=>960} 
#notice key1 is getting changed for dump_data too
```

Same example using `clone`:

```
data = dump_data['ss_usecase_1'][0].clone
data["key1"] = "abc"
dump_data['ss_usecase_1'][0]
# => {"key1"=>"val1", "key2"=>"val2", "key3"=>"45x", "key4"=>"11.26.44.23", "key5"=>"admin", "key6"=>"cup1", "key7"=>960} 
#notice key1 is unchanged
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example:

```
require 'yaml'

data = YAML::load(File.open('1.yml')) # loading 1.yml into data variable
data['ss_usecase_2'][0]['key6'] = 'cup1' # changing key6 under ss_usecase_2
File.open('2.yml', 'w') { |file| file.write(data.to_yaml) } # saving to 2.yml
```

If you want to override existing file just specify it in both `File.open` instructions.