# Write content into yml file from given hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, yaml

I have a `yml` file which contains some information about the databases settings. I need to crate a file which took the content of key and create a file.

like, my yml file:

**db_info.yml**

```
databases:
  database1: # This would be first database
    development:
      adapter: mysql2
      host: localhost
      database: dev1
      password: root
      username: root
      encoding: utf8
    test:
      adapter: mysql2
      host: localhost
      database: dev1_test
      username: root
      password: root
      host: localhost
  database2: # This would be second database
    development:
      adapter: mysql2
      host: localhost
      encoding: utf8
      database: dev
      password: root
      username: root
    test:
      adapter: mysql2
      host: localhost
      database: dev_test
      username: root
      password: root
      host: localhost
```

When I load this `yml` file and try to write individual file information in new `yml` file that saved in wrong manner.

I want to write content in new file like

**new_file.yml**

```
config_file = Rails.root.join('config', 'multiple_database.yml')
file = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.new(config_file).read).result)
```

`file['databases']['database1']` so return me hash

```
{"development"=>{"adapter"=>"mysql2", "host"=>"localhost", "database"=>"dev1", "password"=>"root", "username"=>"root", "encoding"=>"utf8"}, "test"=>{"adapter"=>"mysql2", "host"=>"localhost", "database"=>"dev1_test", "password"=>"root", "username"=>"root", "encoding"=>"utf8"}}
```

So I want to write this content in new `yml` file like

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  database: dev1
  password: root
  username: root
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  database: dev1_test
  username: root
  password: root
  host: localhost
```

**I have tried like this:**

```
array_of_hashes = [{:"client-1.domaine.net"=>"www.client-1.domaine.net/index.html/xxxxxx", :fef => 12}]
File.open("lib/yamlfile.yml","w") do |file|
   file.write array_of_hashes.to_yaml
end
```

So output like this

```
---
- :client-1.domaine.net: www.client-1.domaine.net/index.html/xxxxxx
  :fef: 12
```

Comment: What has your attempted solution got to do with the question?

Comment: I have tried something like this

array_of_hashes = [{:"client-1.domaine.net"=>"www.client-1.domaine.net/index.html/xxxxxx", :fef => 12}]
File.open("lib/yamlfile.yml","w") do |file|
   file.write array_of_hashes.to_yaml
end


But that doesn't seems like `database.yml` as `rails`.

Comment: Actually I tried with simple example

Comment: What has the array: `[{:"client-1.domaine.net"=>"www.client-1.domaine.net/index.html/xxxxxx", :fef => 12}]` got to do with the first 90% of your post?  You talk about reformatting `db_info.yml`, then change the subject. You talk about defining database configurations like `adapter: mysql2`, then change the subject again. I do not understand your question.

Comment: @TomLord, Apologies for that, I am working on application and I pasted my code here, but I tried few things on `console` directly and paste here. Things are different.

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you are trying to solve. "Given this file, I want to produce this file. This is my current method. This is my current result, which is failing because X."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update value of key of a yaml file in ruby on rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948951/update-value-of-key-of-a-yaml-file-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 0):

try applying the method 'to_yaml' to the hash instead of array of hashes. You will get it right

This is your code

```
array_of_hashes = [{:"client-1.domaine.net"=>"www.client-1.domaine.net/index.html/xxxxxx", :fef => 12}]
File.open("lib/yamlfile.yml","w") do |file|
    file.write array_of_hashes.to_yaml
end
```

Do this

```
array_of_hashes = [{:"client-1.domaine.net"=>"www.client-1.domaine.net/index.html/xxxxxx", :fef => 12}]
File.open("lib/yamlfile.yml","w") do |file|
    file.write array_of_hashes[0].to_yaml
                              ^^^
end
```

and check.
Hope it helps